# How to get proper ffplay output with UVC camera?

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, v4l

My end goal is to use a UVC webcam with esp32 or Raspberry PI. I was hoping to learn while doing some fun projects.

I have an old UVC webcam (Creative model ct6840) but I can't seem to get it to work with `ffplay`. I have tried looking through the documentation and other questions here but I can't seem to get it to work. So far I have only been able to achieve a noisy-jittery output.

Running

```shell
ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 640x480 /dev/video2
```

I get:

[image: screenshot of ffplay window popup]

Can someone help me understand how to make the camera work with `ffplay` or `ffmpeg`?

The following is the information of my webcam:

```shellsession
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video2
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x17eb3c0] Compressed: Unsupported :          GSPCA OV511 : 320x240 640x480

$ v4l-info /dev/video2
### v4l2 device info [/dev/video2] ###
general info
    VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
    driver                  : "ov519"
    card                    : "USB Camera (05a9:0511)"
    bus_info                : "usb-0000:00:14.0-8.2"
    version                 : 6.1.79
    capabilities            : 0x85200001 [VIDEO_CAPTURE,?,READWRITE,STREAMING,(null)]

standards

inputs
    VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT(0)
    index                   : 0
    name                    : "ov519"
    type                    : CAMERA
    audioset                : 0
    tuner                   : 0
    std                     : 0x0 []
    status                  : 0x0 []

video capture
    VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT(0,VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    index                   : 0
    type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
    flags                   : 1
    description             : "GSPCA OV511"
    pixelformat             : 0x3131354f [O511]
    VIDIOC_G_FMT(VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
    fmt.pix.width           : 640
    fmt.pix.height          : 480
    fmt.pix.pixelformat     : 0x3131354f [O511]
    fmt.pix.field           : NONE
    fmt.pix.bytesperline    : 640
    fmt.pix.sizeimage       : 614400
    fmt.pix.colorspace      : JPEG
    fmt.pix.priv            : 4276996862

controls
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+0)
    id                      : 9963776
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Brightness"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 127
    flags                   : 48
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+1)
    id                      : 9963777
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Contrast"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 127
    flags                   : 32
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+2)
    id                      : 9963778
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Saturation"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 127
    flags                   : 32
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+24)
    id                      : 9963800
    type                    : MENU
    name                    : "Power Line Frequency"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 2
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 0
    flags                   : 0
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+32)
    id                      : 9963808
    type                    : BOOLEAN
    name                    : "Brightness, Automatic"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 1
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 1
    flags                   : 8
```

Can someone guide me here please? Any advice will be greatly appreciated~

(NOTE: the camera works perfectly with `guvcview` and `xawtv`... so it can work with `ffmpeg`, right?)

Comment: Not clear why you use "rawvideo" as input demuxer if your very next command line shows you should be using "v4l2". And why you're requesting a resolution that doesn't exist

Comment: @sinabala when I run the "rawvideo" code without the next command line, I get an error "Picture size 0x0 is invalid". Typing in the video size removes that error. And thank you for pointing out the resolution bit! it is a typo. correcting it right away